# R - Query JSON and Save to Variable

Tags: r, json, json-query

So I'm trying to clean some data in R, Im not very experinced with R.
What I would like to do is Get a certain peice of Data from a JSON and store it into a Varaible
The JSON is very large and messy,
I tried using JSON Lite and using the $ Variable selector but couldnt find a way to grab the specific peice of Data I needed, Theres very little information and resource out there on JSON Manipulation in R

[Screenshot of JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLKy0.jpg)

JSON File :

```
{
  "error": false,
  "msg": "all countries and population 1961 - 2018",
  "data": [
    {
      "country": "Arab World",
      "code": "ARB",
      "populationCounts": [
        {
          "year": 1960,
          "value": 92197753
        },
        {
          "year": 1961,
          "value": 94724510
        },
        {
          "year": 1962,
          "value": 97334442
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So lets say I want to gather the 1962 Value into a Variable, what would be the best way I do that

Any suggestion would be a huge help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Hey Neil ! Man I am so Sorry!! Lol what i was thinking, I have that fixed now thanks for the Reply Neil (:

Comment: Thanks. I think there was a bit missing at the bottom? I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Lists within Lists,
This can make it sometimes tricky to access the right Data

Break it down:

```
Arab_1962<- myData$PopulationCounts[[1]]
```

- This will access the first listed object which is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right lines with `jsonlite`. The data structure that you get in R depends on the JSON structure itself, of course, so you need to spend some time exploring the object in R to understand how you can manipulate it.

Assuming you have a file like your example data, named `mydata.json` in the current path, you can read it like this:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr) # comes in later

j <- fromJSON("mydata.json")
```

What's in `j` ?

```
names(j)

[1] "error" "msg"   "data"
```

How about `data` ?

```
str(j$data)

'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ country         : chr "Arab World"
 $ code            : chr "ARB"
 $ populationCounts:List of 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ year : int  1960 1961 1962
  .. ..$ value: int  92197753 94724510 97334442
```

So `j$data` is a dataframe with 3 columns. The last one, with the years and values is a list column. So we can get into that using `tidyr::unnest()`:

```
j$data %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(populationCounts))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  country    code   year    value
  <chr>      <chr> <int>    <int>
1 Arab World ARB    1960 92197753
2 Arab World ARB    1961 94724510
3 Arab World ARB    1962 97334442
```

Comment: Neil, I cant thank you enough man, this worked perfectly thanks you so much man you helped me out so much  !  I really appreicate it (: